# How to center a view in parent and add a view below it inside a Relative Layout inside a Scroll view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview, android-relativelayout

I want to make a relative layout which the user can scroll down and has many text views - each one of them below another one starting in the center of the screen.
To do so, I wrap my Relative Layout inside a Scroll View and I have two text views. One of the text view has `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` and the other one has `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` and `android:layout_below="first text view id"`.

The problem is that the `android:layout_below="first text view id"` has no effect: I get the first text view at the center of the screen and the other view at the top of the screen centered horizontally.

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:id= "@+id/chooseMapsScroll">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/chooseMaps"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/title"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="test center in parent"
            android:id="@+id/test_below"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="test center below"
            android:layout_below="@id/test_below"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**UPDATE**
I discovered that the layout's background image is what causing the problem.

The proof:

[That's the output I got without background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmhE2.png)

[That's the output I got with background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wB9UM.jpg)

Comment: `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` will work as `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` with `wrap_content` height . Can you add the expected output ?

Comment: Try to clean project and make sure app is reinstalled correctly. It looks like your layout works as you explained

Comment: @ADM the output should be the first view at the center of the relative layout and the second view centered horizontally and below the first view

Comment: If you are using the preview tool in android studio then try force refreshing the layout. Have a look at this [image](https://imagebin.ca/v/3wPblSnab63P)

Comment: @GiliJacobi Can you upload a screenshot of the view and if possible can you upload the screenshot of the view on an actual device and not preview.
Since olegr , JyotiJk , ADM and me have verified that the code you have given above works as expected.

Comment: I discovered that the background image is what causing the problem. Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this: 
Let me know if there is anything, else this will work for sure
Try going for `LinearLayout` instead

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:id= "@+id/chooseMapsScroll">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chooseMaps"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/title"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="test center in parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="test center below"/>
    </LinearLayout>



</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:id= "@+id/chooseMapsScroll">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chooseMaps"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/title"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="test center in parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="test center below"/>
    </LinearLayout>



</ScrollView>
```

Try this, if didn't work sahre feedback.